# Page.keyDown not fired

Tags: c#, wpf, keydown

I have a page within a navigation window. I need to fire KeyDown events and they won't fire. I have this:

```
 private void gamePlayerPage_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            {
                Animate newAnimate = new Animate(this.myMapController, this);
                newAnimate.animation("right", this.myMinotaur);
            }
        }
```

And it is hooked up correctly. Any ideas how to make it fire? Thanks

Comment: Try handling the `PreviewKeyDown` event instead.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem to work. Is there a bunch of conditions, such as properties that need certain settings for this to work?

Comment: CoreWindow is a WinRT type, why did you use [wpf] tag?

Comment: Please delete your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe adding this to your page load event solve the problem

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MainWindow_KeyDown);
```

Remove the handler if you are going to another page.